# Does GraphQL support objects of multiple types?

Tags: graphql

I run a Java GraphQL server with Apollo client. My model is based on personas - each one can be an 'Actor', 'SoccerPlayer', 'Politician', etc.., all implement the 'Person' interface.
I have a 'Search' field, returning list of 'Person', however one entity might be of two types..
For example, when querying for

```
Search (text: "Ronald Reagan"){
    id
    name
    ... on Actor{
        films{
            name
        }
    }
    ... on Politician{
        party{
            name
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect to get both 'films' and 'party' for the former US president and actor, although typeResolver (on server side) forces me to return only one type. Is this doable at all with GraphQL? Maybe my model is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: I don't believe so. I'm just going off of the Github API search on this, but their "global" search requires you to specify USER, ISSUE, or REPOSITORY in the search, even though the search returns a `SearchResultItemConnection`, which can be any of those 3 types.  The website search results in all 3, so I believe they just run 3 separate queries for each type

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL spec does not allow for multi-level inheritance, so with your specific structure, a `Person` can either be one or the other, but not both `Actor` and `Politician`.

You could get slightly closer to your goal if you turned `Actor` and `Politician` into interfaces themselves, but you'd have to repeat the fields from `Person` in each one as, again, no multi-level inheritance is possible.